# Specifying a join filter between two relations using date

Tags: google-app-maker

I have three tables where I need to join them. However the join has to be based on date.

Model A(EffDate) 1-1 (Model B) 1-Many (Model C - Start - End Date)

The join is that I need to find the model C that matches to the  Start date<= effdate <= End Date

Can this be written as a query? If I just tie using the relation with prefetch, how can I write the additional criteria of the effective date selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time it is not possible to filter relations (App Maker will load *all* related records if prefetch is enabled). Here is a client script that should help:

```javascript
var dsA = app.datasources.DatasourceA;
var filtersA = dsA.query.filters;
var recordC = app.datasources.DatasourceC.item;

filtersA.EffDate._greaterThanOrEquals = recordC.StartDate;
filtersA.EffDate._lessThanOrEquals = recordC.EndDate;

dsA.load();
```